# How to get the turtle follow my IF statement

Tags: python

I am new to programming.  I am trying to code a simple tic tac toe game in which I ask the user to choose where to play.  I am unable to get python to allow me to give the "move" instructions to the turtle.  The code I have so far is below.  (I just started two weeks ago) I created functions that draws, the frame and  x's and o's.  I am now trying to get user input to choose where to place the x or the o.

Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

```
def x_to_nine():
    tic.up()
    tic.left(140)
    tic.forward(16)
    tic.down()
    exx()


x9 = x_to_nine

print(input("Player 1 choose x or o: "))

def player1_choice(x, o):
    if input == x or o:
        print(input("Choose location."))
    if input == x9:
        x_to_nine()
    elif input != x:
        print("You can only choose x or o:")

player1_choice(x, o)
```

Comment: Is there any error printed? My first guess is that the `if input == x or o:` should probably be `if input == 'x' or input == 'o':`instead.

Comment: Actually, I think there's more lacking in this. Are you following a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: what is `x` and `o` and `x9` ? Don't you get error ? You use variables `o`, `x` but you didn't create them (you didn't assign value ie. `o = "o"`) Maybe you should use strings `"x"`, `"o"`

Comment: `input` is function's name and it doesn't have value from user - see `print(input)` . You have to assign to variable ie.  `text = input("...")` and later `if text == "x":`

Comment: @see sharper Thank you for your advice.  Entire code was not posted no tutorial.  I'm practicing by controlling the Turtle which draw a tic tack toe frame and put x's and o's where the player wanted.  The x and o are functions that instructs the turtle to draw them.  The x9 is a part of another series of functions that I did to tell the turtle where the player wants to make their move.  As you know the tic tack toe frame is divided into 9 squares.  I am not too savvy at understanding some of the concepts like flow of execution and that kind of thing.  I'm not giving up but its getting me down.

Answer (score 0):

I see few problems in code.

You have few unknown variables which probably should be strings - `"x"`, `"o"`

`input()` returns string and you should assing it to variable and compare with strings. You can't compare `input == o` because `o` is variable which you didn't defined anb because `input` is function's name and it doesn't keep user answer.

```
answer = input("Player 1 choose x or o: ")
#answer = answer.strip().lower()

if answer == "x":
     # ... code ...
```

You should nest one `if` in another `if`

```
   if text == "x" or text == "o":
        location = input("Choose location.")
        location = location.strip().lower()
        print(location)
        if location == "x9":
            x_to_nine()
    else:
        print("You can only choose x or o:")
```

You should send user's answer to function.

```
def player1_choice(text):
    if text == "x" or text == "o":
       # code

# --- main ---

answer = input("Player 1 choose x or o (or exit): ")
player1_choice(answer)
```

It will get string from `answer` and assing to variable `text` and later you use `text inside function

---

```
# --- functions ---

def x_to_nine():
    tic.up()
    tic.left(140)
    tic.forward(16)
    tic.down()
    exx()

def player1_choice(text):

    if text == "x" or text == "o":
        location = input("Choose location.")
        location = location.strip().lower()
        print(location)
        if location == "x9":
            x_to_nine()
    else:
        print("You can only choose x or o:")

# --- main ---

while True:
    answer = input("Player 1 choose x or o (or exit): ")
    answer = answer.strip().lower()
    print(answer)

    if answer == "exit":
        break

    player1_choice(answer)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.  Especially about the part of sending the user's answer to a function.  I'm learning as I go along but a lot of things confuse me and sometimes I just believe I'm over thinking everything.